# How to create a console application to run automatically when windows start

Tags: c#, .net, console-application

How to create a console application to run automatically when windows start in C#?
How can I do this the programmatically.I tried this whay...

```
 RegistryKey rkApp = 
 Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey
 ("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run   ", true);
 rkApp.SetValue("MyAPP", Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
```

but SetValue metho not found in current context.

Comment: I don't know if `OpenSubKey` trims, but "Run   " ought to be different to "Run".

Comment: can you give me some example

Comment: Also see https://superuser.com/questions/689108/how-can-i-add-an-item-to-the-startup-list-in-msconfig

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use CurrentUser instead of LocalMachine:

```
RegistryKey rkApp = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", true);
```

Remove the space after \Run, and use the following to set the value:

```
rkApp.SetValue("MyApp", Application.ExecutablePath);
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Built project to file .exe
2. Create a shortcut to the batch file.
3. Once the shortcut has been created, right-click the file and select Cut.
4. Press the Start button and type Run and press enter.
5. In the Run window, type shell:startup to open the Startup folder.
6. Once the Startup folder has been opened, click the Home tab at the top of the folder and select Paste to paste the shortcut into the folder.

Comment: I want to do it programmatically sir.